# Grab the name of an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i have an array populated with objects, 10 to be exact, all with individual names.

```
var upgrades = [
tree = {price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0},
irr = {price: 80, rate:1, owned:0},
press = {price: 150, rate:2, owned:0},
cracker = {price: 400, rate:7, owned:0},
gmo = {price: 1000, rate:10, owned:0},
shack = {price: 1500, rate:13, owned:0},
truck = {price: 2000, rate:14, owned:0},
factory = {price: 5000, rate:18, owned:0},
rr = {price: 9000, rate:25, owned:0},
mGadget = {price: 15000, rate:30, owned:0},
];
```

I want to be able to grab the name of the object and be able to assign this to a string variable.

```
var x=upgrades[0].getObjName
```

Theoretically x should now equal 'tree'; How do i do this without adding a variable called name to my objects?

Comment: That's not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Im sorry i dont follow, what do you mean?

Comment: It's not valid JSON, but it's still an object, but with this syntax you are inadvertently creating global variables. `tree` isn't actually a key for this object but a global variable.

Comment: This is not a valid structure: `tree = {price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0}`, probably you wanted to share something like this: `{tree: {price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0}}`

Comment: This is not valid javascript.

Comment: @Pytth It definitely is, see my comment above. It creates global variables. `upgrades` is also a valid object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code you are creating global variables rather than keys for the objects in the array. So first, you need to fix the syntax so that you actually have an array of objects. It should look like this:

```
var upgrades = [
  { tree: {price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0} },
  { irr: {price: 80, rate:1, owned:0} },
  { press: {price: 150, rate:2, owned:0} },
  { cracker: {price: 400, rate:7, owned:0} },
  { gmo: {price: 1000, rate:10, owned:0} },
  { shack: {price: 1500, rate:13, owned:0} },
  { truck: {price: 2000, rate:14, owned:0} },
  { factory: {price: 5000, rate:18, owned:0} },
  { rr: {price: 9000, rate:25, owned:0} },
  { mGadget: {price: 15000, rate:30, owned:0} },
];
```

After that, you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the first (and in this case only) key for the object:

```
var x = Object.keys(upgrades[0])[0];
console.log(x); // --> tree
```

Comment: Eureka! Thank you, i dont have the best understanding of object properties, but this is now something ill never forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is wrong.There should be no identifier for array elemens.It should be like this

```
var upgrades = [
 {price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0},
 {price: 80, rate:1, owned:0},
 {price: 150, rate:2, owned:0},
 {price: 400, rate:7, owned:0}

];
```

Thus you can not get an element of array by name.You get it by index

```
var x = upgrades[0]
```

if you want to use named identifier to grab element then you need to use object instead of array

```
var upgrades = {
    tree : {price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0},
    irr : {price: 80, rate:1, owned:0},
    press : {price: 150, rate:2, owned:0},
    cracker : {price: 400, rate:7, owned:0}

}

var x = upgrades.tree
```

***check by identifier in array :***

Follow this example to grab array element by identifier.Just add a property to your objects in upgrades array called identifier, and search for specific identifier

```
var upgrades = [
   {identifier : 'tree',price: 20, rate:0.5, owned:0},
   {identifier: 'tiger',price: 80, rate:1, owned:0}

];

var obj = upgrades.filter(function(elem,index){
   return elem.identifier == 'tree'
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: @Pytth: You can run this code at the console of the browser, it is valid JS. As skyline3000 mentioned, 'tree' will be treated as global var.

Comment: Al-zami, i forgot to specify, but i need upgrades to be an array. If its not an array i have to go and redesign 90% of my code.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake then go for the first example.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake check the updated answer.I hope it will solve your issue

Comment: @Al-zami i just realized what everyone meant when they said im declaring global variables. So the only way for me to grab a string out of an array of objects is if i declare it inside one of the objects. Am i correct on this?

Comment: yes you are right.That's what i''ve done in my updated answer